# Add hotkey when editing a NSTextField

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextfield

Is it possible to add hotkeys only when you're editing a certain NSTextField?  For example, when you're in this text field I would like it if you pressed Command + 1 it inserted one string, and Command + 2 to insert another text string, etc, but only when you're editing that NSText field.

I tried adding a keyDown method to my subclassed NSTextField, but that didn't seem to ever get fired.  If I changed it to keyUp it gets fired, but not if the command key is held down.

It seems when I'm searching for hotkeys the only information I find is on global hotkeys (ones that activate even when the app isn't visible) which isn't what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If you had a menu item with that keyboard shortcut, you could implement `validateUserInterfaceItem:` to enable it when your field is in the responder chain.  What I'm not sure about is whether that would work for a hidden menu item.

Comment: +1 for experimenting down this path.  Menus are already equipped with this functionality, so start with one and if you really don't want the menu item, try making it invisible and see if the keyboard equivalent still works.

Comment: My app is an "Agent" and doesn't have a MainMenu, unfortunately so I'm not sure if I can do that.

Answer (score 1):

NSTextField's to not deal with keyDown: themselves.  They instead seem to rely on intermediaries called Field Editors (found this info from a similar question here http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/51299-custom-nstextfield-keydown.html).

Apple has some more info on the subject - http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextEditing/Tasks/FieldEditor.html

Answer (score 0):

I ended up subclassing my window and overriding sendEvent when my text field is the first responder.